# Related on coding in batch scripts

Tags: batch-file

I read the deploy_landscape from the user:

```
IF "%deploy_landscape%" == "Europe_Canary--LP_Performance" GOTO abcd
:abcd
(
echo Inside the second loop
set landscape=lpitstw7186bb8d
echo Landscape is %landscape%
GOTO EXIT
)
```

I get the output as

```
Landscape is
```

I do not see the actual value of landscape being printed.
I have also tried `set landscape="lpitstw7186bb8d"` and `set "landscape=lpitstw7186bb8d"`

Comment: remove `(` and `)`

Comment: Please provide a specific question title! Read the [tour] and learn [ask]!

Answer (score 1):

You need to read some of the SO articles on `delayed expansion` - there are many of these.

Within a block statement `(a parenthesised series of statements)`, the **entire** block is parsed and **then** executed. Any `%var%` within the block will be replaced by that variable's value **at the time the block is parsed** - before the block is executed - the same thing applies to a `FOR ... DO (block)`.

Hence, `IF (something) else (somethingelse)` will be executed using the values of `%variables%` at the time the `IF` is encountered.

Two common ways to overcome this are 1) to use `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` and use `!var!` in place of `%var%` to access the changed value of `var` or 2) to call a subroutine to perform further processing using the changed values.

Note therefore the use of `CALL ECHO %%var%%` which displays the changed value of `var`. `CALL ECHO %%errorlevel%%` displays, but sadly then RESETS errorlevel.

Comment: I guess @Magoo is pretty annoyed by the amount of questions about delayed expansion.